# Sketchup model > Collada > THREE js = no edges

Tags: three.js, collada, sketchup

I exported a very simple Sketchup model into a Collada dae file. When imported back into Sketchup edges are the original black; imported into THREE editor edges are white; in simple THREE project edges don't appear at all but everything else seems OK. Any ideas about this?

Answer (score 0):

I found your problem just yesterday because i had the same problem and was searching the web for a solution. Nothing... but i solved it.

First of all make sure that when you export Collada from Sketchup, in options button **Export Edges** is checked.

If the edges are white and you want them to be black or any color you must edit one line in three.js

search for

```
    function LineBasicMaterial( parameters ) {

    Material.call( this );

    this.type = 'LineBasicMaterial';

    this.color = new Color( 0xffffff );

    this.linewidth = 1;
    this.linecap = 'round';
    this.linejoin = 'round';

    this.lights = false;

    this.setValues( parameters );

}
```

and change this line

```
this.color = new Color( 0xffffff );
```

to this

> this.color = new Color( 0x000000 );

I hope this solves your problem